# htaccess for load subdomain with parameters

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I would like to know how I can get a second parameter when I load data from an htaccess, I have everything working so that I get the first parameter that is the subdomain, the second parameter would be the "GET" that it gets from the URL, for example:

I want to load:
subdomain.domain.com/category?idx=22

With the following code I get the first parameter that is the subdomain but I can't get the idx after category

This is the code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI} /%1" !^(/[^/]+)[^\s]*\s\1$
RewriteRule ^category$ loader-category.php?&id=%1&idx=$2 [L]
```

what's the correct regex for this?
I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

> RewriteRule ^category$ loader-category.php?&id=%1&idx=$2 [L]

What would `$2` be referring to here? You don’t have any capturing groups in the pattern.

Use the `QSA` flag here, so that the original query string gets appended / merged with the new one you are creating.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

```
RewriteRule ^category$ loader-category.php?id=%1 [L,QSA]
```